# Алгоритм Флойда-Уоршелла

Tags: pascal, c++

У меня есть задание....дан граф, представленный матрицей смежности. Для каждой пары вершин определить, существует ли кратчайший путь между ними или нет. Если существует, то в матрицу смежности вывести 1, если нет, то 0, если путь бесконечно мал вывести -1

```
Код C++
#include <iostream>
const int inf=1E9;
using namespace std;
int main()
{  
 int n,i,j,k,d[100][100];
 scanf("%d",&n);           //считывание из файла
 for (i=0;i<n;++i)
  for (j=0;j<n;++j)
  {
   scanf("%d",&d[i][j]);
  }

 for (k=0;k<n;++k)            //Алгоритм Флойда-Уоршелла 
  for (i=0;i<n;++i)
   for (j=0;j<n;++j)
    if (d[i][k]<inf && d[k][j]<inf) d[i][j]=min(d[i][j],d[i][k]+d[k][j]);

 for (i=0;i<n;++i)
   for (j=0;j<n;++j)
if (d[i][j] > 0) d[i][j]=1;

for (i=0;i<n;++i)
   for (j=0;j<n;++j)
if (d[i][j] < 0) d[i][j]=-1;

  for (i=0;i<n;++i,printf("\n"))    // вывод на консоль результата
  for (j=0;j<n;++j)
 printf("%d ", d[i][j]);
}
```

входной файл:

```
0 2 2
2 0 3
2 3 0
```

выход:

```
-1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

Но это неверно!
Должно быть:

```
1 1 1 
1 1 1 
1 1 1
```

Что я делаю неверно?
Или может у кого есть реализация этого алгоритма для графов с отрицательными весами?

Comment: Расскажете, почему вы не воспользовались отладчиком? (Наверняка проблема в scanf и концах строк. Или нет.)

Comment: @VladD, а как добавить проверку на цикл отрицательного веса?

Comment: @dimchik: попробуйте [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). А проблема, о которой вопрос, решилась?

Comment: @dimchik, Вы наверное гоняете одну программу, а сюда скопипастили другую.

1). на scanf будет ругань (надо \#include <stdio.h> добавить)

2). отрицательным числам при таких исходных данных не откуда здесь взяться.

Comment: @avp: теоретически, если scanf завершился с ошибкой, значение считанных элементов может быть каким угодно, в частности, отрицательным. Код `if (d[i][j] < 0) d[i][j]=-1;` подчистит неожиданные значения.

---
стоп! там же первым стоит `scanf("%d",&n);`! вот только скажите, что отладчик не нужен :) входной файл начинается с нуля.

Comment: @VladD, там всё норм это просто не весь входной файл)...вначале файла стоит количество вершин

Comment: @avp, это просто пример исходных данных, а программа должна работать для любых

Comment: @dimchik: вы уверены, что данные читаются правильно? вы уже проверили это с отладчиком? извините, но мне не хочется запускать отладчик за вас (даже если бы вы дали рабочий входной файл).

Comment: @VladD, я похоже уже нашёл свою ошибку Алгоритм Флойда-Уоршелла работает с матрицей кратчайших путей, а не с матрицей смежности, так ведь или нет?